# Is it possible to create print templates in 2.6 and 2.8?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is this possible? I can only find the option to 'Add items from template'. When using this option, the page setup defaults to A4 landscape and you must manually change these settings using the composition tab within the print composer.

Version 2.4 and earlier did not need this extra step. Applying a pre-saved print composer not only loaded in all the objects previously saved within the template but also replicated the page set-up

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create one directly from a template using the composer manager.

Project>Composer Manager...

In there you can add a new print composer based on a specific template.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I should have dug around a bit more to find this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dan, if the answer has resolved your question please mark it as correct. Green arrow next to the voting for answers, this helps to keep the forum orderly and gives me internet points that I can use to brag at work with.